# mongo $unwind and $group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have two collections. One of which I wish to add a reference to the other and have it populated on return.

Here is an example json I am trying to achieve as the result:

```
{
  "title": "Some Title",
  "uid": "some-title",
  "created_at": "1412159926",
  "updated_at": "1412159926",
  "id": "1",
  "metadata": {
    "date": "2016-10-17",
    "description": "a description"
  },
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "Tag 1",
      "uid": "tag-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tag 2",
      "uid": "tag-2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tag 3",
      "uid": "tag-3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the mongo query I have which gets my close, but it nests the original body of the item within the `_id` object.

```
db.tracks.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$tags"
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "tags",
        localField: "tags",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "tags"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$tags"
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": {
            "title": "$title",
            "uid": "$uid",
            "metadata": "$metadata"
        },
        "tags": {
            "$push": "$tags"
        }
    }
}])
```

So the result is this:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "title" : "Some Title",
        "uid" : "some-title",
        "metadata" : {
            "date" : "2016-10-17",
            "description" : "a description"
        }
    },
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("580499d06fe29ce7093fb53a"),
            "name" : "Tag 1",
            "uid" : "tag-1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("580499d06fe29ce7093fb53b"),
            "name" : "Tag 2",
            "uid" : "tag-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired output? Also is there a way to not have to define in the `$group` all the fields which I wish to return, I would like to return the original Object but with the referenced documents in the `tags` array.

Comment: What do `tags` and `tracks` collections look like?

Comment: Why don't you have a look at `$project`? Anything here it cant solve?

Comment: @hyades the tracks collections looks like the first json snippet above except for the `tags` array is an array of ObjectIds from the `tags` collection. The `tags` collection is just `name` & `uid` (& ObjectId). Doesn't the `$project` offer the same as the `$group`? I am not too familiar with either if you could show me an example of `$project` that would be great.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since you had initially pivoted your original documents on the `tags` array field which means the documents will be denormalized, your **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline should 
use the `_id` field as its `_id` key and access the other fields using the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** operator.

The group pipeline operator is similar to the SQL's `GROUP BY` clause. In SQL, you can't use `GROUP BY` unless you use any of the aggregation functions. The same way, we have to use an aggregation function in MongoDB as well, so unfortunately there is no other way of not having to define in the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline all the fields which you wish to return apart from using the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** operator on each field:

```
db.tracks.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$tags" }, 
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "tags",
            "localField": "tags",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "resultingArray"
        }
    }, 
    { "$unwind": "$resultingArray" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "title": { "$first": "$title" },
            "uid": { "$first": "$uid" },
            "created_at": { "$first": "$created_at" },
            "updated_at": { "$first": "$updated_at" },
            "id": { "$first": "$id" },
            "metadata": { "$first": "$metadata" },
            "tags": { "$push": "$resultingArray" }
        }
    }
])
```

---

One trick I always use whenever I want to debug a pipeline that's giving unexpected results is to run the aggregation with just the first pipeline operator. If that gives the expected result, add the next.

In the answer above, you'd first try aggregating just the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)**; if that works, add the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)**. This can help you narrow down which operator is causing issues. In this case, you could run the pipeline with just the first three steps since you believe the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** is the one causing issues and then inspect the resulting documents from that pipeline:

```
db.tracks.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$tags" }, 
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "tags",
            "localField": "tags",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "resultingArray"
        }
    }, 
    { "$unwind": "$resultingArray" }
])
```

which yields the output

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5804a6c900ce8cbd028523d9"),
    "title" : "Some Title",
    "uid" : "some-title",
    "created_at" : "1412159926",
    "updated_at" : "1412159926",
    "id" : "1",
    "metadata" : {
        "date" : "2016-10-17",
        "description" : "a description"
    },
    "resultingArray" : {
        "name" : "Tag 1",
        "uid" : "tag-1"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5804a6c900ce8cbd028523d9"),
    "title" : "Some Title",
    "uid" : "some-title",
    "created_at" : "1412159926",
    "updated_at" : "1412159926",
    "id" : "1",
    "metadata" : {
        "date" : "2016-10-17",
        "description" : "a description"
    },
    "resultingArray" : {
        "name" : "Tag 2",
        "uid" : "tag-2"
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5804a6c900ce8cbd028523d9"),
    "title" : "Some Title",
    "uid" : "some-title",
    "created_at" : "1412159926",
    "updated_at" : "1412159926",
    "id" : "1",
    "metadata" : {
        "date" : "2016-10-17",
        "description" : "a description"
    },
    "resultingArray" : {
        "name" : "Tag 3",
        "uid" : "tag-3"
    }
}
```

From inspection you will see that for each input document, the last pipeline outputs 3 documents where 3 is the number of array elements in the computed field `resultingArray` and they all have a common `_id` and the other fields with the exception of the `resultingArray` field which is different, thus you get your desired results by adding a pipeline that groups the documents by the `_id` field and subsequently getting the other fields with **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** operator, as in the given solution:

```
db.tracks.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$tags" }, 
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "tags",
            "localField": "tags",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "resultingArray"
        }
    }, 
    { "$unwind": "$resultingArray" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "title": { "$first": "$title" },
            "uid": { "$first": "$uid" },
            "created_at": { "$first": "$created_at" },
            "updated_at": { "$first": "$updated_at" },
            "id": { "$first": "$id" },
            "metadata": { "$first": "$metadata" },
            "tags": { "$push": "$resultingArray" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks that is a great explanation of how the pipelines work. Is there a way to push the `$resultingArray` without having to define all of the existing fields I wish to keep?

Comment: As explained in the most recent edit; The group pipeline operator is similar to the SQL's `GROUP BY` clause. In SQL, you can't use `GROUP BY` unless you use any of the aggregation functions. The same way, you have to use an aggregation function in MongoDB as well, so unfortunately there is no other way of not having to define in the `$group` pipeline all the fields which you wish to return apart from using the `$first` or `$last` operator on each field:

Comment: Thank you @chridam I can't plus one your answer due to my lack of reputation.